# search a string for another string that contains a special character

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So right now I'm using this simple method to check a string for another string:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(toSearch, toVerifyisPresent, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Now, its working fine for the most part. But my biggest issue is that if I try to search for something like "areyou+present", if "areyou+present" IS there, it will still come back false. I'm thinking its because of the "+" in the string.

What can I do to work around this?

Comment: What's wrong with `string.Contains`?

Comment: What does your regex look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment above by [Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded).

```
toSearch.toLowerCase().Contains(toVerifyIsPresent.toLowerCase())
```

Converting both to lowercase will provide the same functionality as using `IgnoreCase`

Comment: Better yet: `toSearch.IndexOf(toVerifyIsPresent, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1`

Answer (score 3):

You can escape special characters using a `\`.  But as Oded points out if you are just checking to see if a string contains something you are better off using the `String.Contains` method.

Special Characters in regex:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

String.Contains method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Comment: Also if you use `\` to escape the `+` don't forget to escape the `\` with another `\` - in other words `"areyou\\+present"` should do it or `@"areyou\+present"`.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions `+` matches the previous group one or more times so the regex `areyou+present` matches:

```
areyoupresent
areyouupresent
areyouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuupresent
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Demo in IronPython:

```
>>> from System.Text.RegularExpressions import *
>>> Regex.IsMatch("This is a sentence containing 'areyou+present'", "areyou+present");
False
>>> Regex.IsMatch("This is a sentence containing 'areyou+present'", "areyou\\+present");
True
>>> Regex.IsMatch("This is a sentence containing 'areyou+present'", "areyou[+]present");
True
>>> Regex.IsMatch("This is a sentence containing 'areyou+present'", Regex.Escape("areyou+present"));
True
```